# YouTube force video to play in HTML5 mode

Tags: video, youtube, html5, lubuntu

I am a Lubuntu user and find Flash to be extremely laggy on it. I signed up for the YouTube HTML5 beta and, after a while was able to watch videos using the HTML5 player. However, recently videos started playing using Flash again. How can I force YouTube to show me videos using the HTML5 player?

Comment: instead of using flash or some flash plugin, install chrome, it has flash built in and it's good

Answer (score 1):

Not all video on Youtube are available with the HTML5 player : [see youtube info](http://www.youtube.com/html5).

> Additional Restrictions (we are working on these!)
>
> - Some videos with ads are not yet supported (they will play in the Flash player)
> - On Firefox and Opera, only videos with WebM transcodes will play in HTML5
> - If you've opted in to other testtube experiments, you may not get the HTML5 player (Feather is supported, though)

Depending on your browser and its capacity to open `WebM` or `h.264` videos, not the same videos are available in HTML5 mode.

Comment: Actually, it's a bit stranger than that. You see, videos that played in HTML5 mode before no longer do, even though I am using the same browser.

Comment: @dillmo Given the workaround you found, I think it must be linked to the part about advertising.

Comment: Maybe. I am using an ad blocker, so it is possible the ad never fully registers that it is no longer running.

Answer (score 0):

I was going from video to video trying to find out what is wrong and finally solved the problem. I noticed that only embedded videos play in HTML5 mode. As a result, you cannot just watch them on YouTube. My workaround was to create a blank HTML document and copy the embed code for the video into there, then watch it. If you have a better solution, please tell me.

I hope this solves the issue for anyone who has this same issue. You will need to know how to code HTML to do this.